# jdk 1.4, 1.5, 1.6 compiled code differences

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am using a web application were the java code is compiled using jdk 1.4 and i use weblogic 8.1 as my app server which also use jdk 1.4, but there are few finger countable class files compiled using jdk 1.5. Its something like a mix of class files together compiled using jdk 1.4 & 1.5. Now when i try to access the part of application which requires the class files compiled with 1.5 jdk to be executed in order. It will throw ClassDefnNotFound exception.

Any suggesstions.?. I also would require an explaination on the differences between class files compiled using jdk 1.4 and jdk 1.5, if there are any .

Thanks in advance

Comment: Java is backwards compatible, not forwards compatible.  So you can run code compiled on javac 1.4 on a 1.5 jvm, but not the other way around.  Either upgrade the jvm you use to execute the code, or downgrade the 1.5 code, taking out the 1.5 features (like generics) and compile it with javac 1.4 (or the 1.4 compatibility flag in 1.5).

Comment: Will there be any difference in the bytcodes or the compiled codes using different jdk's(eg: 1.4 & 1.5 in this case). If so, how would a JVM recognize it rather address it while execution.

Comment: I believe there is a header in the class file that sas the version.  And yes, there is a difference in the bytecodes - 1.5 needs to support generics and some other stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you need [retroweaver](http://retroweaver.sourceforge.net/) to back-convert your newer code, if you are really using newer features. If you are not, set -target to 1.4 when compiling everything.